# Android Studio API Call

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I basically have everything functioning following this tutorial on how to implement a API in flutter: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data. I followed the tutorial but i get an error message "type 'null is not a subtype of 'String'". I have tried adding additional parameters to the header, but that haven't solved the problem.
The API im using is a car registry, where you can type in a numberplate and get all the details for a vehicle.

```
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://v1.motorapi.dk/vehicles/CZ33849'),
       headers: {"X-AUTH-TOKEN": "rfrzsucnc7eo3m5hcmq6ljdzda1lz793",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
      });

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

//headers: {"X-AUTH-TOKEN": "rfrzsucnc7eo3m5hcmq6ljdzda1lz793"}

class Album {
  final String registration_number;
  final String status;
  final String type;
  final String use;
  final String first_registration;
  final String vin;
  final int doors;
  final String make;
  final String model;
  final String variant;
  final String model_type;
  final String color;
  final String chasis_type;
  final String engine_power;
  final String fuel_type;
  final String RegistreringssynToldsyn;
  final String date;
  final String result;

  Album({
    required this.registration_number,
    required this.status,
    required this.type,
    required this.use,
    required this.first_registration,
    required this.vin,
    required this.doors,
    required this.make,
    required this.model,
    required this.variant,
    required this.model_type,
    required this.color,
    required this.chasis_type,
    required this.engine_power,
    required this.fuel_type,
    required this.RegistreringssynToldsyn,
    required this.date,
    required this.result,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      registration_number: json['registration_number'],
      status: json['status'],
      type: json['type'],
      use: json['use'],
      first_registration: json['first_registration'],
      vin: json['vin'],
      doors: json['doors'],
      make: json['make'],
      model: json['model'],
      variant: json['variant'],
      model_type: json['model_type'],
      color: json['color'],
      chasis_type: json['chasis_type'],
      engine_power: json['engine_power'],
      fuel_type: json['fuel_type'],
      RegistreringssynToldsyn: json['RegistreringssynToldsyn'],
      date: json['date'],
      result: json['result'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Album> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Album>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.registration_number);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the Json response from the API (I tested the API in python):

```
{'registration_number': 'CZ33849', 'status': 'Registreret', 'status_date': '2021-03-18T10:53:23.000+01:00', 'type': 'Personbil', 'use': 'Privat personkørsel', 'first_registration': '2020-03-17+01:00', 'vin': 'WVWZZZAWZLY087322', 'own_weight': None, 'total_weight': 1650, 'axels': 2, 'pulling_axels': 1, 'seats': 5, 'coupling': False, 'trailer_maxweight_nobrakes': 590, 'trailer_maxweight_withbrakes': 1000, 'doors': 4, 'make': 'VOLKSWAGEN', 'model': 'POLO', 'variant': '1,0', 'model_type': 'AW', 'model_year': 0, 'color': None, 'chassis_type': 'Hatchback', 'engine_cylinders': 3, 'engine_volume': 999, 'engine_power': 70, 'fuel_type': 'Benzin', 'registration_zipcode': '', 'vehicle_id': 9000000003974700, 'mot_info': {'type': 'RegistreringssynToldsyn', 'date': '2021-03-16', 'result': 'Godkendt', 'status': 'Aktiv', 'status_date': '2021-03-16'}}
```

Comment: I think this error produce when compile ---{'color': None , 'own_weight': None } ---in your json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have marked all the `fields` in your `Album` class as `required` just make them `nullable` so that is `API` returns something `null` then `class` can handle that as well.
Make following changes to your class

```
class Album {
  final String? registration_number;
  final String? status;
  final String? type;
  final String? use;
  final String? first_registration;
  final String? vin;
  final int? doors;
  final String? make;
  final String? model;
  final String? variant;
  final String? model_type;
  final String? color;
  final String? chasis_type;
  final String? engine_power;
  final String? fuel_type;
  final String? RegistreringssynToldsyn;
  final String? date;
  final String? result;

  Album({
    this.registration_number,
    this.status,
    this.type,
    this.use,
    this.first_registration,
    this.vin,
    this.doors,
    this.make,
    this.model,
    this.variant,
    this.model_type,
    this.color,
    this.chasis_type,
    this.engine_power,
    this.fuel_type,
    this.RegistreringssynToldsyn,
    this.date,
    this.result,
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      registration_number: json['registration_number'],
      status: json['status'],
      type: json['type'],
      use: json['use'],
      first_registration: json['first_registration'],
      vin: json['vin'],
      doors: json['doors'],
      make: json['make'],
      model: json['model'],
      variant: json['variant'],
      model_type: json['model_type'],
      color: json['color'],
      chasis_type: json['chasis_type'],
      engine_power: json['engine_power'],
      fuel_type: json['fuel_type'],
      RegistreringssynToldsyn: json['RegistreringssynToldsyn'],
      date: json['date'],
      result: json['result'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have made the changes but get error in this line: `return Text(snapshot.data!.registration_number);` And the error is: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: As @Diwhansh answer, keep in mind null-safe package is usable by packages and apps that don't use null safety yet, as long as they use Dart 2.12 or later

Comment: @WaiHanKo please check that in MyApp  Key is defined nullable which means that the project is in null safety already.

Comment: @mhmh just convert in to string using .toString() method Text(snapshot.data!.registration_number.toString()) or you can do it as Text("${snapshot.data!.registration_number}")

Comment: @Diwyansh I have made the changes but now i get an error message: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?'

Comment: Just put that value as I stated above Text("$value") or for simple final data = "$value"

Comment: @mhmh 'engine_power' is int not String you cast wrong type in your class.

Comment: @Diwyansh Thanks for ur help :) i finally got it to work. How can i display all the information from the album class?

Comment: There are many ways to do so using FutureBuilder and passing data using Statemanagement tools or calling this function with .then() and assigning value to your desired value. Also please mark this as answer if it helped.

Comment: @Diwyansh Thanks so much for helping, can you tell me how to do it? Or provide a tutorial on how to do it

Comment: Please go through the article if you find it hard then you can search for Provider and Getx  also https://medium.com/solidmvp-africa/making-your-api-calls-in-flutter-the-right-way-f0a03e35b4b1